# Problems displaying django syntax in html when using ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

I have an article where i allow people to comment.
When the user clicks on the reply button in a submitted comment an ajax request is being sent to retrieve html from a file to add a new element to the DOM that contains the reply form.

I'm using this code:

```
function handle_ajax_request(event) {
    if ( request.readyState === 4) {
        if (request.status === 200 || request.status === 304) {
            console.log("AJAX request from get_reply_form was received successfully from the server.");
            parentElement = document.getElementById("reply_comment");
            reply_form_element = document.createElement("div");
            reply_form_element.id = "reply_comment_form";
            parentElement.appendChild(reply_form_element);
            reply_form_element.innerHTML = request.responseText;
        } else {
            console.log("Error: AJAX request from get_reply_form failed!");
        }
    }
}

function get_reply_form(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    reply = document.getElementById("reply_comment");

    request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    if (! request) {
        console.log("Error: Unable to create AJAX request.")
    }

    console.log("Created ajax request, checking for state.");
    request.onreadystatechange = handle_ajax_request;
    request.open("GET", "http://localhost:8000/static/html/experience/comment_reply_form.html", true);
    request.send(null)
}
```

I fetch this file with the ajax request:

```
{% load comments %}
{% get_comment_form for article_details as form %}
<form action="{% comment_form_target %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.object_pk }}
  {{ form.content_type }}
  {{ form.timestamp }}
  {{ form.security_hash }}

  {% if node.id %}
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="parent" id="parent_id" value="{{ node.id }}" />
    </div>
  {% endif %}

  {{ form.comment }}
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="next" value="/article/display/{{ article_details.id }}" />
      <input type="submit" class="form-control" value="Reply">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

As you can see there is some django template syntax code in that html.
When i add this html to a div on the page it works except from that the django syntax is not being interpreted by django for some reason and i dont understand why its not being interpreted normally.

I literally get this displayed:

```
Posted by an anonymous user 4 days, 20 hours ago
test
Reply
{% get_comment_form for article_details as form %}
{% csrf_token %} {{ form.object_pk }} {{ form.content_type }} {{ form.timestamp }} {{ form.security_hash }} {% if node.id %}
{% endif %} {{ form.comment }}
```

The django syntax is being display literally and should not be visable at all if it was interpreted by django. Why doesnt this work ?

In the html code a " is inserted before the django syntax for some reason, i dont know why and a " is added at the end. Also, its seem that every time a { is encountered a " is put in front of it and a " is put at the end and i dont know why.

I'm not using jquery since im currently learning about javascript and i like to learn the plain version as welll and not just frameworks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making a get request against a static HTML template. You should be making the request against a URL that calls a view, like any other Django page.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense so django knows about it and parses it, thanks, ill try that.